# How can I remove irrelevent sessions from an informatica workflow or start new one from scratch?

Tags: oracle, workflow, informatica, informatica-powercenter

How can I remove irrelevent sessions from an informatica workflow? I spent 15 minutes on Google and I also couldn't find how to close a workflow to start from scratch, which I also would like to know. Each time I open the last session appears. I foolishly clicked on the session and used the delete key and then it removed all kinds of necessary files/directories (mapping, source and target... Which I had to remake and import again). I am glad I am in development mode because when I ran a workflow it truncated my source deleting all data, luckily it loaded it into my target destination so now I have to copy the same tables in opposite order. I bet it's simple, perhaps in my Oracle (I use Toad 12.1.0.3). Would someone please help somebody brand new to ETL? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. On the mapping designer there's and option to close mapping. I also figured out that on target designer and source designer you can right click and "clear workspace". In addition if you select all in workflow you can find an options menu which has a check box by default that says open up last task when opening folder and uncheck. That doesn't work for me because I have so many different tasks. I hope this helps somebody.